# Подскажите,как сделать такую треугольную выемку, это два соседних блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как сделать такую треугольную выемку? Это два соседних блока.

Answer (score 2):

```css
section.section1, section.section2{
height:50vh;
}
body {
margin:0;
}
section.section1 {
background:#fafafa;
position:relative;
filter:drop-shadow(0 0 10px black);

}
section.section1:before {
content: '';
position:absolute;
height:10px;
top:100%;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%);
border:15px solid transparent;
border-top:15px solid #fafafa;
}
section.section2 {
background:url(http://fototips.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/landscape_03.jpg);

}
```

```html
<section class="section1"></section>
<section class="section2"></section>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.foto {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 170px;
  background-image: url(https://i2.tabor.ru/feed/2016-05-19/13145096/49398_760x500.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 40% 0, 50% 30%, 60% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="foto"></div>
```

Comment: еще бы про поддержку браузерами инфу добавить...